# Look up values which are equal to zero in one file and than replace the zero value with found value

Tags: awk

I have a data like this:

```
head out_sign.txt
chr    pos    gene_id    p.val.LCL  p.val.Retina
chr1 756164 ENSG00000237094 0 7.15853e-05
chr1 775930 ENSG00000237094 0 9.72251e-05
chr1 814583 ENSG00000237094 0 1.88553e-05
chr1 815963 ENSG00000237094 0 3.85837e-06
chr6 130235069 ENSG00000164484 5.43098e-06 0
chr17 45848600 ENSG00000236234 9.005e-06 0
chr11 34862454 ENSG00000110435 1.81973e-06 0
chr17 45979467 ENSG00000236234 1.34927e-05 0
chr5 81234109 ENSG00000248794 4.36795e-06 0
```

so sometimes p.val.LCL is ==0 and sometimes  p.val.Retina==0.

Every times one of them is equal to zero I would like to look up the corresponding combination of: chr, pos, gene_id in these two files:

for p.val.LCL==0 look up in file called: "lcls.txt" for the combination of chr, pos, gene_id  file and replace the zero value with the one found in "lcls.txt"

```
head lcls.txt
chr pos gene_id pval_nominal
chr1 756164 ENSG00000237094 0.1
chr1 775930 ENSG00000237094 0.4
chr1 814583 ENSG00000237094 0.6
chr1 815963 ENSG00000237094 0.7
```

for

p.val.Retina==0 look up the combination of chr, pos, gene_id in "ret.txt" file and replace the zero value with the one found in "ret.txt"

```
head ret.txt
chr pos gene_id pval_ret
chr6 130235069 ENSG00000164484 5.43098e-06
chr17 45848600 ENSG00000236234 9.005e-06 
chr11 34862454 ENSG00000110435 1.81973e-06
chr17 45979467 ENSG00000236234 1.34927e-05
chr5 81234109 ENSG00000248794 4.36795e-06
```

So for this given example the SOLUTION would be:

```
chr    pos      gene_id         p.val.LCL   p.val.Retina
chr1  756164    ENSG00000237094 0.1         7.15853e-05
chr1  775930    ENSG00000237094 0.4         9.72251e-05
chr1  814583    ENSG00000237094 0.6         1.88553e-05
chr1  815963    ENSG00000237094 0.7         3.85837e-06
chr6  130235069 ENSG00000164484 5.43098e-06 5.43098e-06
chr17 45848600  ENSG00000236234 9.005e-06   9.005e-06
chr11 34862454  ENSG00000110435 1.81973e-06 1.81973e-06
chr17 45979467  ENSG00000236234 1.34927e-05 1.34927e-05
chr5  81234109  ENSG00000248794 4.36795e-06 4.36795e-06
```

The Solution file would have the same number of lines like out_sign.txt.

I should mention that these files are fairly large, number of lines in each file is:

```
107371529 ret.txt
166941636 lcls.txt
2250213 out_sign.txt
```

Probably awk solution would be the best because of the size of the data.
I tried doing this in R but I am getting memory related error. awk should be able to handle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible to implement using awk script

```
awk '
t == "lcls" { if ( FNR > 1 ) lcls[$1, $2, $3] = $4 ; next }
t == "ret" { if ( FNR > 1 ) ret[$1, $2, $3] = $4 ; next }

        # Lookup for main file
{
        if ( $4 == 0 ) { v = lcls[$1, $2, $3] ; if ( v ) $4 = v ; }
        if ( $5 == 0 ) { v = ret[$1, $2, $3] ; if ( v ) $5 = v ; }
        print
}
' t=ret ret.txt t=lcls lcls.txt t= out_sign.txt
```

It load the lookup files into awk tables, and then perform the replacement on the 'data' file. The 't' variable indicate the input 'type'.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for getting back to me. I tried your code, with redirecting output like: lcls.txt t= out_sign.txt > res_tpr.txt And in this output file I get this: Rchrposgene_id=pval_ret
Rchr110177ENSG00000227232=0.381708
Rchr110352ENSG00000227232=0.959523
Rchr111008ENSG00000227232=0.218132

Comment: I would need output as I specified in my post.

Comment: the with with results, made with your awk command has 276563378 lines

Comment: I've removed the debug printout 'Rchr...' an d 'Lchr...'

Comment: Thank you so much this is fantastic!

Answer (score 0):

I think the approach by @dash-o is maybe more elegant. However, just for fun, here is another method in the vein of a [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform), to distinguish the three input files into `awk`, drop the header line and then prefix each line with `L`, `R` or `D`.

So, if you use:

```
sed '1d; s/^/L /' lcls.txt
sed '1d; s/^/R /' ret.txt
sed '1d; s/^/D /' out_sign.txt
```

you'll get this:

```
L chr1 756164 ENSG00000237094 0.1
L chr1 775930 ENSG00000237094 0.4
L chr1 814583 ENSG00000237094 0.6
L chr1 815963 ENSG00000237094 0.7
R chr6 130235069 ENSG00000164484 5.43098e-06
R chr17 45848600 ENSG00000236234 9.005e-06 
R chr11 34862454 ENSG00000110435 1.81973e-06
R chr17 45979467 ENSG00000236234 1.34927e-05
R chr5 81234109 ENSG00000248794 4.36795e-06
D chr1 756164 ENSG00000237094 0 7.15853e-05
D chr1 775930 ENSG00000237094 0 9.72251e-05
D chr1 814583 ENSG00000237094 0 1.88553e-05
D chr1 815963 ENSG00000237094 0 3.85837e-06
D chr6 130235069 ENSG00000164484 5.43098e-06 0
D chr17 45848600 ENSG00000236234 9.005e-06 0
D chr11 34862454 ENSG00000110435 1.81973e-06 0
D chr17 45979467 ENSG00000236234 1.34927e-05 0
D chr5 81234109 ENSG00000248794 4.36795e-06 0
```

Now you can `awk` like this:

```
{ sed '1d;s/^/L /' lcls.txt; sed '1d;s/^/R /' ret.txt; sed '1d;s/^/D /' out_sign.txt; } | 
   awk '
       /^L/ {lcls[$2,$3,$4]=$5; next}    # build "lcls" table
       /^R/ {ret[$2,$3,$4]=$5;  next}    # build "ret" table
       /^D/ {... per dash-o lines starting "if" but field numbers incremented ... }'
```

Or, if you like `bash` process-substitution, this is equivalent:

```
awk '...' <(sed '1d; s/^/L /' lcls.txt) <(sed '1d; s/^/R /' ret.txt) <(sed '1d; s/^/D /' out_sign.txt)
```

Comment: You can also do: `awk '{print p,$0}' p=L lcls.txt p=R ret.txt p=D out_sign.txt`

Comment: this does not give me output I need, please see my post where is say Solution. With this code I am getting: L chr pos gene_id pval_nominal
L chr1 13550 ENSG00000227232 0.375614

Comment: @MarkSetchell I tried your awk command and I am getting this error: awk: cmd. line:1: ...
awk: cmd. line:1: ^ syntax error